# Composer packages "Hotfixes" without version change

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I have a `composer.json` file with some packages in specific versions. So I am sure that every time i run `composer update` I will retrieve exactly the SAME code as before.

But there are some application authors and companies that produce "**hotfixes**". That means they fix something in their code without changing the `version`.

Do you know if this thing can happen in composer's `packages`?

If yes, then every time I download packages using composer.json i cannot be sure that I get the same code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you run `composer update`. You should never do that unless you want to get newest commit of the package you use.

Each time you use `composer.json` also `composer.lock` file is generated and in case you commit this in repository (for example GIT) you should always commit both `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. Now if you (or someone else) in future will want to install your application and will run `composer install` they will get exact same commits that are saved in `composer.lock`.

So the simple rule is - when you want to install the same, you should have `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and run `composer install` and in case you want to update all packages to the versions you have in `composer.json` you should run `composer update`